# Border on only part of full width background

Tags: html, css

I want to show a bottom border on my main full width background header but not on the far left side of the screen.

Full width background header is 100%
Main body is 1200 pixels centred, border at the bottom needs to extend across the page full width but not on the section before logo.

As the website is responsive it is difficult to not show on the first section as this only appears on larger screens.

```css
#headerBackground {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#headerBackground header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerBackground">

  <header>

    <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/logo.jpg" width="200" height="54" alt="">
    </div>

  </header>

</div>
```

with current setup border appears across the full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via pseudoelement of `<header>` element plus `overflow: hidden` property for `#headerBackground` element

Result (RUN ON FULLPAGE)

```css
#headerBackground {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  /* border-bottom: 3px solid black; */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#headerBackground header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
  min-height: 50px;
}

#headerBackground header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200vw;
  height: 3px;
  background: #000;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerBackground">

  <header>

    <div id="logo">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" width="200" height="54" alt="">
    </div>

  </header>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?
Header centered on screen with the logo also centered?

```css
#headerBackground {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#headerBackground header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 105px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#logo {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}
#logo img{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerBackground">

  <header>

    <div id="logo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
    </div>

  </header>

</div>
```